# Using ASP.NET identity to do external oauth logins, how can add parameters to the facebook authorization endpoint? I want to pass "display=popup"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 6 (.net core).  With it, i'm using the built in external login logic in order to authenticate with facebook.

I've made a modification to it so that instead of authenticating within the same window, i'm launching a popup and authenticating there. Once successful, the popup closes itself and tells my main window to redirect.  This all works.

However, I want to use the "smaller/mini" version of the facebook login page.  This can be seen here:
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?display=popup

"display=popup" is what is controlling it.

I don't see how i can inject this kvp in my C# code. Where can i do it?

```js
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions
                              {
                        // was hoping for something here... tried to stick it into the authorizationurl but then i end up with 2 question marks and it fails
                              AppId = "blah",
                              AppSecret = "blah"
                              });
```

```js
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);

          // Don't see anything here... 
          
            return Challenge(properties, provider);
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint` event:

```
        var facebookOptions = new FacebookOptions
        {
            AppId = "",
            AppSecret = "",
            Events = new OAuthEvents()
            {
                OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = ctx =>
                {
                    ctx.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri + "&display=popup&pip");
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        };

        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

Comment: You deserve a lot more credit.  Just curious, is this documented somewhere?

Comment: I guess here.. https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Authentication/OAuth/OAuthEvents/